# Is cloning the only way to implement prototype design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am wondering if I can implement prototype design pattern without cloning technique.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2):

No you can't implement prototype design pattern without cloning technique.

Because Prototype design patterns recommends cloning an existing object to create a copy of it, instead of creating a new object using the time consuming initialization. You can implement different cloning techniques but you can't escape from cloning technique.

Comment: Can you add additional explanation of why not? It would significantly enhance the usefulness of this answer.